# Тэг <oembed> не распознается React - ом

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

Использую модуль CKEDITOR для React. При создании видео контента, видео не отображается, [выходит такая ошибка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ0YH.png)

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './AddNews.css';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { useState } from 'react';
    import $ from 'jquery';
    import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
    const parse = require('html-react-parser');
    
    const AddNews = () => {
        const[league, setLeague] = useState('none');
        const[title, setTitle] = useState('');
        const[img, setImg] = useState('');
        const[content, setContent] = useState('');
        const[disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
    
        const addNews = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            if(league === 'none') {
                alert('Выберите лигу');
            }
            else if(title === '') {
                alert('Введите заголовок');
            }
            else if(img === '') {
                alert('Вставьте ссылку на изображение');
            }
            else if(content === '') {
                alert('Введите контент для новости');
            }
            else {
                $('.preview').fadeIn();
                $('body').css({overflow: "hidden"});
            }
        }
    
        const rejectAdd = () => {
            $('.preview').fadeOut();
            $('body').css({overflow: "auto"});
        }
    
        const acceptAdd = () => {
            axios.post('/addNews', {
                league,
                title,
                img,
                content
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if(err) throw err;
            });
    
            $('select').prop({selectedIndex: '0'});
            document.querySelector('#newsSubmit').innerHTML = '✓';
            document.querySelector('#newsSubmit').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            document.querySelector('#newsLeagues').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            document.querySelector('#newsTitle').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            document.querySelector('#newsImg').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            document.querySelector('#newsSubmit').style.background = '#18ba20';
            $('.preview').fadeOut();
            $('body').css({overflow: "auto"});
            setDisabled(true);
            setContent('');
            $('input').val('');
    
            setTimeout(() => {
                document.querySelector('#newsSubmit').innerHTML = '+';
                document.querySelector('#newsSubmit').removeAttribute('disabled');
                document.querySelector('#newsLeagues').removeAttribute('disabled');
                document.querySelector('#newsTitle').removeAttribute('disabled');
                document.querySelector('#newsImg').removeAttribute('disabled');
                document.querySelector('#newsSubmit').style.background = 'rgba(204, 135, 45, 0.9)';
                setDisabled(false);
            }, 10000);
        }
    
        return (
            <div id='addNews'>
                <form action='/addNews' method='POST'>
                    <label htmlFor="newsLeagues">Лига:</label>
                    <select onChange={(e) => {
                        setLeague(e.target.value);
                    }} defaultValue={'none'}  name="newsLeagues" id="newsLeagues">
                        <option value="none" disabled>Не выбрана</option>
                        <option value="rpl">РПЛ</option>
                        <option value="epl">АПЛ</option>
                        <option value="laliga">Ла Лига</option>
                        <option value="seriea">Серия А</option>
                        <option value="bundesliga">Бундеслига</option>
                        <option value="ligue1">Лига 1</option>
                        <option value="ucl">ЛЧ</option>
                        <option value="uel">ЛЕ</option>
                        <option value="uecl">ЛК</option>
                        <option value="wc">ЧМ</option>
                        <option value="ec">ЧЕ</option>
                    </select>
                    <label htmlFor="newsTitle">Заголовок:</label>
                    <input placeholder='Введите заголовок' onChange={(e) => {
                        setTitle(e.target.value);
                    }} type="text" id='newsTitle' name='newsTitle' />
                    <label htmlFor="newsImg">Изображение:</label>
                    <input placeholder='Вставьте ссылку на изображение' onChange={(e) => {
                        setImg(e.target.value);
                    }} type="text" name='newsImg' id='newsImg' />
                    <label id='newsContentLabel' htmlFor="newsContent">Контент:</label>
                    <CKEditor config={{placeholder: "Введите описание новости"}} data={content} disabled={disabled} id="newsContent" editor={ClassicEditor} onChange={(e, editor) => {
                        setContent(editor.getData());
                    }} />
                    <button title='Предпросмотр' type='submit' id='newsSubmit' onClick={addNews}>+</button>
                </form>
    
                <div className="preview">
                    <p className="popupTitle">Предпросмотр</p>
    
                    <div className="container">
                        <p className="pageName">{title}</p>
                        <span className="date">ДД-ММ-ГГГГ | ЧЧ:ММ</span>
                        <img src={img} alt="newsImg" />
                        <div className="textWrap">{parse(content)}</div>
                    </div>
    
                    <button title='Подтвердить' type='submit' className='acceptBtn' onClick={acceptAdd}>✓</button>
                    <button title='Отклонить' type='submit' className='rejectBtn' onClick={rejectAdd}>⨯</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default AddNews;
```

UPD: Отрывок кода в странице, где появляется тег "oembed":

```
<div class="postWrap">
    <h1 class="pageName">Mr.Kitty - After Dark</h1>
    <span class="date">02-10-2022 | 18:18</span>
    <img alt="newsImg" src="https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/waAlgFq9Xq8/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&amp;sqp=CJCHipsG&amp;rs=AOn4CLCaMY_qlXdR65tAYezTmB7qIrgHqw">
    <div class="textWrap">
    <figure class="media">
        <oembed url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waAlgFq9Xq8"></oembed>
    </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: тег oembed я вижу только в заголовке вопроса, в коде не нахожу. Общее замечание, в REACT не надо работать с DOM вне реактовских механизмов. Вам надо переписать код так, что бы избавиться от манипуляций с DOM вне компонента и вне функции render. Вы такими действиями вызываете мутацию, которая может привести к неожиданному поведению вашего приложения.

Comment: Тег появляется при добавлении поста, т. е. он динамически появляется. Могу примерно показать структуру самой страницы с содержанием oembed

Comment: Судя по ругани react, вы пытаетесь добавить компонент не реакт методами. Пока вы не уберете все побочные действия вида document.querySelector, jquery функции, искать причину ошибки и способы ее устранения преждевременно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам `warning` возникает по причине выполнения этой проверки в **REACT-DOM**:

```
  if (!isCustomComponentTag && Object.prototype.toString.call(domElement) 
     === '[object HTMLUnknownElement]' 
     && !hasOwnProperty.call(warnedUnknownTags, type)) {
        warnedUnknownTags[type] = true;
    error('The tag <%s> is unrecognized in this browser. ' 
      + 'If you meant to render a React component, start its name with ' 
      + 'an uppercase letter.', type);
  }
```

Тут основной момент — сравнение `'[object HTMLUnknownElement]'` как будет написано ниже `oembed` это не HTML элемент. Cудя по [этой спеке](https://oembed.com/#section2) `<oembed>` — это тэг не `html` a `xml` и больше рассчитан на `CRM` такие как  `WordPress`

**Решение 1 (хак):**

Для подавления указанного выше варнинга, вставить этот в index.js до рендера:

```
const origELToString = Object.prototype.toString
Object.prototype.toString =  function(){
  if (this instanceof Element && this.tagName === 'OEMBED'){
    return '[object XMLOembedElement]'
  }
  return origELToString.call(this) 
}
```

**Решение 2:**

В `Реакте` я бы предпочел использовать `<iframe>` для тех же целей, он отлично справляется с аудио, видео, `pdf`, изображениями в качестве содержимого.

Что касается `youtube`, то там вообще есть свое [api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) которое позволяет работать с `плеером`, его лишь нужно "поднастроить" под `React` (вызывать инициализацию 1 раз и т.п.) в зависимости от того, что из себя представляет Ваше приложение. Но тег

```
<script src ="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api" </script>
```

нужно **импортировать не более одного раза на все приложение**, не зависимо от того сколько у вас будет фреймов с видео, поэтому его можно встроить даже в основной шаблон `html` хотя это и может сказаться на начальной загрузке странице, поэтому возможно стоит добавить еще `lazy-loading`

**Решение 3 (согласно документации):**

Исследовав документацию я нашел [опцию](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_media-embed_mediaembed-MediaEmbedConfig.html#member-previewsInData) которая заданная через атрибут `config` позволяет выбрать `iframe` в качестве компонента:

```
<CKEditor
    editor={ ClassicEditor }
    config = {{
        mediaEmbed: {previewsInData: true }
    }}
```

Comment: Я тоже предпочитаю <iframe>, но модуль CKEDITOR, который предназначен для текста в React, позволяет добавлять видео (медиа контент) только с помощью тега <oembed>. Поискал в документациях того же модуля, как можно сменить тег с <oembed> на <iframe>, но ничего не нашел

Comment: С удалением <StrictMode> ничего не получилось, хотя как вы указали, не стоит этого делать

Comment: @MuradImanov Вы имеете в виду этот инструмент https://ckeditor.com/ ?,  В принципе, я сам не очень люблю ошибки в консоли, но если все работает и не крашиться можно на это забить, понимаю - так себе ответ, но фиксить платный инструмент чревато))

Comment: Да, все верно. Все же видео контент в дальнейшем необходим, поищу какие то альтернативы. Так то сам разработчик и мне понятно, что можно просто встроить iframe, но поймет ли обычный клиент как добавить, то видео... Поищу альтернативы

Comment: @MuradImanov  Думаю, третье решение на основе документации, позволяет не искать другие альтернативы.

Comment: 3 ий вариант как раз подошел, спасибо!)